# Select a record and select next row

Tags: php, mysqli

If I have a table with records

ANIMALS

> > cat
> >
> > dog
> >
> > cow
> >
> > rat

How do I select the next animal cow after I select dog?

Comment: Explain how the ordering in the table is defined.

Comment: Animals are inserted without specific ordering.

Comment: Then the output will also have no defined ordering, and the problem looks unsolvable. You can read the whole table until you find the first match. Then read the next entry and you are done.

Comment: @U.Windl thanks, I thought as much